# Display pages in cards wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I will try to explain it.

I have pages for doctors and i have a custom template so they can create a page and add data to it and it will display in the template page.

But now i need a list of all the doctors. So i need to get all the pages of the doctors and exclude the sitepages.

I tried this but i only get the title of the current page.

```
            <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post(); 
                    //
                    the_title();
                    the_content();
                    //
                } // end while
            } // end if
            ?>
```

Is this even possible? And if it is, how?

Comment: I think the best you can do in your case is to have 1 category(doctors for example) and create these pages (doctors pages) as posts. Then on the page where you want to show the list of doctors, you'll just call the posts from "doctors" category and thats it ... In this way, even with the time you add more doctors(posts), they will show in your list automatically.

Comment: @AngelDeykov yes but then i need to create a post when i create a new doctorpage?

Comment: Are "doctors" considered as users? Do they have their own login? If so you can just call a user list and filter for user role

Comment: @amarinediary yes they are users and have their own login. How can i do that?

Comment: @ARVOCI, Posted an answer to your last comment

Comment: @amarinediary is right, I didn't quite get the issue you had ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer to your last comment: (Not tested)

```
<?php $args = array(
'role' => 'subscriber',
//      If custom role exist, replace "subscriber" by custom role
//      More on roles @: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#roles
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will call a userlist of all the doctors and than link their page. Thanks to everyone who helped!